# Refresh NSviewcontrollers in OS X

Tags: macos, refresh, reload, viewcontroller

I am developing OS X App,I have two view controllers 1) Profile .h &.m 2)Settings .h &.m, If both are open with profile behind Settings then how can i refresh or reload profile viewcontroller on button click on settings

Comment: what do you mean by refresh? Redraw? Update with new data? Simplest solution can be to send NSNotification. Personally I recommend you to read some beginner book (e.g big nerd ranch). Also post demo code so people can see what you have already tried.

Comment: I mean  refresh or reload as changing values in Profile which is active behind settings, so when user changes value from settings then at the same time profile should get updated

Comment: Please attach demo app with what you have already tried. As I have mentioned, use notifications to propagate the change or nsuserdefaults

Comment: Notification works,thanks  xhruso00

Comment: you refer link to update values in active NsviewController http://stackoverflow.com/a/32836137/5179979